# NodeJs File timestamp resolution to 1 second

Tags: node.js, deb

NodeJs changed the resolution of timestamp from 1second to 1 milisecond in https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7000

Is it somehow still possible to create files with 1 second precision only?

I am creating a deb package and uploading to a local aptly repository, but the problem is that there is an incoming hook(which I cannot change), that cannot handle millisecond precision

timestamps:

`1495726502.2107`, `1495726502.2107`

```
$ xxd stuff.deb | head -10
0000000: 213c 6172 6368 3e0a 6465 6269 616e 2d62  !<arch>.debian-b
0000010: 696e 6172 792f 2020 3134 3935 3732 3635  inary/  14957265
0000020: 3032 2e32 3130 3720 2020 3131 3320 2020  02.2107   113   
0000030: 3130 3036 3434 2020 3420 2020 2020 2020  100644  4       
0000040: 2020 600a 322e 300a 636f 6e74 726f 6c2e    `.2.0.control.
0000050: 7461 722e 677a 2f20 3134 3935 3732 3635  tar.gz/ 14957265
0000060: 3032 2e32 3130 3720 2020 3131 3320 2020  02.2107   113   
0000070: 3130 3036 3434 2020 3133 3430 3620 2020  100644  13406   
0000080: 2020 600a 1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0003 ed7d    `............}
0000090: 6b6f 234b 92dd 7ed6 af68 c39f d9ca f763  ko#K..~..h.....c
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in whatever you're using to create the .deb file? Have you submitted an issue to the relevant project (e.g. the tar/zip/whatever module)?

Comment: `Math.round(timestamp)`?

Comment: @mscdex :I don't think that it is invalid, but I have not seen any official specification yet

#robertklep the timestamp is generated internally in node core

Comment: @q99 Based on a quick overview of the tar file spec(s), it should be an integer and not a floating point number, so it does seem like a bug to me.